# How to calculate numers inside an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to check some Numbers for a color recognition. I'm new to python so please do not judge me.

```
thresholdR = 50
thresholdG = 50
thresholdB = 50
middleValue = [225,165, 25]
    
lowerBound = [middleValue - thresholdR/2,middleValue - thresholdG/2,middleValue - thresholdB/2]
upperBound = [middleValue +  thresholdR/2,middleValue + thresholdG/2,greenMiddle + thresholdB/2]
```

When I try to run this I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'
```

I don't know how to fix this I would be so pleased if you could help me!

Comment: `middleValue` is a list. You can't subtract a value from it. Do you want to calculate those lower/upper bounds for every element of `middleValue`?

Comment: Did you mean: `middleValue[0] - thresholdR/2` to mean red value - threshold/2?

Comment: @kuro yes thats right so I would have to use middleValue[0], middleValue[1] and middleValue[2] ?

Comment: @MrSpoony, yes. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @kuro Yes It solves it! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add array indexers to your middleValue references.

```py
lowerBound = [middleValue[0] - thresholdR/2,middleValue[1] - thresholdG/2,middleValue[2] - thresholdB/2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not just substract a integer from a list.
Maybe u mean this

```
lowerBound = [middleValue[1] - thresholdR/2,middleValue[2] - thresholdG/2,middleValue[3] - thresholdB/2]
upperBound = [middleValue[1] +  thresholdR/2,middleValue[2] + thresholdG/2,middleValue[3] + thresholdB/2]
```